# $3(a+{1\over a}) = 4(b+{1\over b}) = 5(c+{1\over c})$ and $ab+bc+ca=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, euclidean-geometry, triangles

This was the question :

> $3(a+{1\over a}) = 4(b+{1\over b}) = 5(c+{1\over c})$ where $a,b,c$ are positive number and $ab+bc+ca=1$ ,
>
> $5({1-a^2\over 1+a^2}+{1-b^2\over 1+b^2}+{1-c^2\over 1+c^2}) =  ?$

I have spent a lot of time trying rearranging the terms and combine the two conditions to get the required expression but I couldn't get the right form.

I wrote it like :

$5({2\over 1+a^2}+{2\over 1+b^2}+{2\over 1+c^2} -3) $

This seemed simpler than the required expression , I could not come up with anything else useful.

Could someone please help me in solving this question ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you mean $3(a+{1\over a}) = 4(b+{1\over b}) = 5(c+{1\over c})$, with $c$ rather than $b$ in that last term?

Comment: yes , I've corrected it

Comment: Similar https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3133577/find-the-number-of-ordered-triplets-satisfying-5-leftx-frac1x-right-12-l

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hint.

Let $a=\tan\frac{\alpha}{2},$ $b=\tan\frac{\beta}{2}$ and $c=\tan\frac{\gamma}{2},$ where $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}\subset(0^{\circ},180^{\circ}).$

Thus, $ab+ac+bc=1$ gives $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=180^{\circ}$ and the rest gives 
$$\frac{3}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{4}{\sin\beta}=\frac{5}{\sin\gamma},$$ which gives $\gamma=90^{\circ}$ and $c=1.$

Can you end it now?

Since $c=1$, we obtain: $$b\in\{2,\frac{1}{2}\}$$ and $$a\in\{3,\frac{1}{3}\},$$
but since $$ab+ac+bc=1,$$ we obtain:
$$(a,b,c)=\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},1\right).$$

Comment: +1 interesting approach of mapping it to a triangle. BTW, $a,b,c$ are given to be positive.

Comment: @achille hui Thank you! I fixed. If so, we obtain an unique solution.

Comment: I am able to solve now , thanks a ton , there is just one doubt , it is very clearly visible that $/gamma$ is equal to 90 degress (Considering the right triangle with sides 3,4,5 ) . But how can I "prove" that properly.

Comment: @ARROW Do you know the Law of Sines? This can tell you precisely what the sides of your triangle are (up to scaling).

Comment: @ARROW We proved that $\alpha,$ $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are measured angles of a triangle. But by law if sines if $x$, $y$ and $z$ are sides-lengths of the triangle so $x:y:z=3:4:5$, which says $\gamma=90^{\circ}$ because $x^2+y^2=z^2.$

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I know , that's why I took that triangle's example . I was just not sure whether the converse has a unique solution for the angles or not .

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg , Understood , BTW , I was just in doubt regarding the uniqueness of the solution.

Comment: @ARROW We proved that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=180^{\circ}$, which says that there is a triangle with such angles.

Comment: @Macavity a=1/3 , b=1/2 , c=1 , also satisfies all the conditions . Could you please tell how you concluded that those are the only real solutions ?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg , yes , got it .

Comment: @ARROW Your solution and $(-\frac13, -\frac12, -1)$ are the only real ones, the method is in the similar linked post which had slightly different coefficients (which i missed).